# Generic TypeDef does not work with custom class

Tags: generics, dart, flutter

I want to create a generic `class(Test< T, F>)` but with some variable(`_cellBuilder`) that has an external `typedef` `type(CellBuilder)` outside the class. `testA` with `String` assigned runs fine, but `testB` failed just as the screenshot shows.

And when I remove `<Product>` from `testB`, I get a different error.

```
type '(Product) => Widget is not a subtype of type (dynamic) => Widget
```

Quite confusing. Any help please?

[image]

```
void main() {

  testA<String>(String content) {
    print(content);
  }

  Widget testB<Product>(Product item) {
    print(item.a);
  }

  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    Test<int, Product> c = Test(testA, testB);
    c.eval();
  });
}

class Product {
 final String a;
 Product(this.a);
}

typedef CellBuilder<F> = Widget Function(F item);
typedef testString<T>(T text);

class Test<T, F> {
  final testString _f;
  final CellBuilder _cellBuilder;
  Test(testString this._f, CellBuilder this._cellBuilder);
  eval() {
    _f("hello");
    _cellBuilder(Product("world"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
Widget testB(Product item)
```

not a generic function:

```
Widget testB<Product>(Product item)
```

`Product` is a generic identifier, not the type you are expecting for the argument.

If you write in the custom way:

```
Widget testB<T>(T item)
```

The error should now make sense.